# Getting binding from View Model to work on a GMapPanel

Tags: google-maps, extjs, google-maps-api-3, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Good afternoon!

I have a page where I display a form and a map, and the form displays the data I have in my view model through binding just fine.

However when I try to do the same in my map (so I have the client address as the map center's address and their name as title of the marker) it doesn't seem to even recognize that line in the code exists: the center requests a latitude and longitude it'd need if geoCodeAddr weren't in place and the marker simply doesn't have a title.

Here's the code of my map panel

```
xtype: 'gmappanel',
gmapType: 'map',
center: {
    bind:{
        geoCodeAddr: '{client.address}'
    }, 
    marker: {
        bind:{
            title: '{client.address}'
        }
    }
},
mapOptions : {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

The binds work just fine anywhere else but in the map, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Binding these values is not implemented by default, as far as i can read it from the docs, code here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.ux.GMapPanel.html